# Add a new contact to an Outlook mailbox using EWS Managed API and link it to Exchange Server

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I know how to add a new contact to a mailbox, like explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee693007(v=exchg.80).aspx).

But, when you add a new contact this way, it's like manually adding a contact to your Outlook contacts list. The information will be static and will never get updated. What I need to do is to add a contact that already exists on the same Exchange Server, and somehow link it to the existing mailbox on the server, so the contact's information gets updated as the information changes in AD or on the Exchange Server. This will be like adding a contact from Outlook's Address Book to your contact list, as opposed to manually creating a new contact. Is there any way you can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Contact is always a separate Exchange Store object in a Mailbox so they aren't linked in anyway. If you have the Social connector enabled (OSC) in Outlook then this component can perform a synchronization for you (one way only) see http://www.msoutlook.info/question/599 .Otherwise if you want properties to be synced then you will need to create your own application that synchronizes that data manually.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thank you! That link was very helpful.